# Connect Oracle 11g using PowerShell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I have a 64 bit Windows 10 PC with Oracle 11g client installed to `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1`.

I can connect to a DB using `sqlplus` and the included `perl` 5.10.0 DBI. So everything looks nice.

I would like to connect from `PowerShell` (v5.1). Under `ODP.NET\bin\2.x\` I have found `Oralce.DataAccess.dll` v2.112.1.0 (I do not know if `OraProvCfg.exe` was run or not), but no `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`. All EXEs and DLLs seems to be 64 bit version (I checked using `7z l *`. I'm a bit confused here. 7z says: *CPU = x64; 64-bit = +; Characteristics =  Executable DLL 32-bit* (???)).

I cannot install anything or change any registry entry on this machine.

I tried:

1. `System.Data.OracleClient`

   $env:ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1
   Add-type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient
   $con_str = "User Id=$username;Password=$password;Data Source=$data_source"
   $sql = "select user from dual"

   $con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($con_str)
   $con
   $con.Open()

`$con` is written nicely, but during the execution of `$con.Open()` it drops an error:

**Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."**

2. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`

`[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oralce.DataAccess.dll")`

But this failed immediately:

**Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, ...' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

Do you have any idea how could I make this work? Or this is an impossible mission? I try to avoid to call `sqlplus` or `perl` code from `PowerShell`.

TIA!

Comment: Is your Powershell session 64 bit one? Use `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` to find out.

Comment: Kudos is yours! I launched both `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`and `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and voil`a, the second worked! Thanks!

Comment: I found the reason of my confusion. I edit the script in Notepad++, I use the tab menu: `Open Containing Folder in cmd` which launches C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe. Then I launch powershell, which is the 32 bit version! But if I launch cmd using Win+R and then I run powershell, it launches the 64 bit version. So, I was cheated... :) Thanks!